# Composer throws syntax error in browsercap.ini

Tags: php, composer-php, httpbrowsercapabilities

I downloaded `full_php_browscap.ini` from https://www.browscap.org/

When I do `composer update`, I get the ff. error:

`PHP:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ']' in /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/full_php_browscap.ini on line 102`

This is lines `100` - `103` for reference (without the numbering prefix):

```
100) RenderingEngine_Maker="Microsoft Corporation"
101)
102) [Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0*; *Windows NT 6.2*Win64? x64*Trident/4.0*)* 360Spider]
103) Parent="360Spider"
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please share more details - what's the connection between that ini file and Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obviously cannot parse an `*.ini` file with PHP directly; use [`parse_ini_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) instead. That log says nothing about composer... you've probably just added that `*.ini` into the wrong directory. If you'd move it outside of the web-root or anywhere else where it won't get scanned when running `composer update`, that should work.

Comment: Yeah I just transferred it elsewhere, thanks!